# python shape too large to be a matrix

Tags: numpy, matrix, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm use python keras to build a cnn model.

I follow cnn mnist example and modify to my code.
This is the example I found

```python
# Read MNIST data  
(X_Train, y_Train), (X_Test, y_Test) = mnist.load_data()  
# Translation of data  
X_Train40 = X_Train.reshape(X_Train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1).astype('float32')  
X_Test40 = X_Test.reshape(X_Test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1).astype('float32')
```

My data has 30222 rows and 6 columns of csv.

Which is 10074 data each data is 3 * 6 size for one block of information.

For example, the 1 ~ 3row of the matrix is one block of information.

Then I changed the format of my data.

```python
X_Train40 = X_Train.reshape(10074, 3, 6, 1)
X_Test40 = X_Test.reshape(4319, 3, 6, 1)
```

Then this error occurs.

```python
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-133-4f23172d450a> in <module>()
----> 1 X_Train40 = X_Train.reshape(10074, 3, 6, 1)
      2 X_Test40 = X_Test.reshape(4319, 3, 6, 1)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\matrixlib\defmatrix.py in __array_finalize__(self, obj)
    269                 return
    270             elif (ndim > 2):
--> 271                 raise ValueError("shape too large to be a matrix.")
    272         else:
    273             newshape = self.shape

ValueError: shape too large to be a matrix.
```

Comment: What does - `python shape to large to be a matrix` mean?

Comment: Are you using `np.matrix`? if so, try `np.array(X_Train).reshape(10074, 3, 6, 1)`

Comment: @JulioDanielReyes Thank you! It's work!

Comment: Glad it worked, I'll put that as the answer, just in case someone else have this problem

Comment: A `matrix` array can only have 2 dimensions; so can't be reshaped to 4d.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just guessing, but since the data comes from a csv file, it was converted to `np.matrix`, which have the restriction to be 2-dimensional.

Internally numpy will try to keep the dimensions of the matrix, so to reshape to higher dimensions, you will need to convert it to a `ndarray` like this:

```
X_Train = np.array(X_Train)
X_Test = np.array(X_Test)
X_Train40 = X_Train.reshape(10074, 3, 6, 1)
X_Test40 = X_Test.reshape(4319, 3, 6, 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You know... I had this problem today and I could not find a single answer that helped.

Your problem is probably solved at this point, but one thing to look at when python complains about "shape too large to be a matrix" is the type of your variable, namely, ***is it a numpy.matrix data type or a numpy.ndarray***?

If it is the former, then you are in troubles.

Try to avoid numpy.matrix type, specially if you want to do any linear algebra operations, or stack them (with (d/v/h)stack, etc) and stick to numpy.ndarray